# Alternate title replacing Product Title

Tags: commerce, entities

This is a combobox showing a group of product referenced.

[image]

I have created an extra field in product list, short_title. How do I replace the Product Title with short_title? i.e. Chicken, Turkey, Pork, … Is this possible?

I’ve also tried Inline Form Entity. The YouTube tutorial: http://youtu.be/glRM_NzNVTA?t=5m3s : When the host edited the Variation Title, the Product Title remained unchanged. However, when I do it, the Product Title changed. Is this by design or the host was using an older version of Inline Entity Form?

I know that we can create attributes, but having a variety of product types complicates the form. All I wanted: one product type and just reference a group of product in product display.

The Product Title is too long in combo, but I can't shortened that because it's important as line-item title.

Any idea or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'simple' selection, use a view for your entity reference. Here you can decide yourself how the title is shown.

Comment: How do you create a view filter and put in product display page? Could you please give me the steps?